# ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:edit` on Rails 7.0.5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I get that error when deploying Rails API to render. I tried to follow the instructions of May 2nd by Jason FB and when I enter 'EDITOR=nano credentials:edit --environment production' it returns 'command not found'. I am using wls2. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: `EDITOR=nano RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails credentials:edit`? otherwise, you might find that you've got a rogue file sitting in your config folder